# when JSONP call showing “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ”

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Here is my code

```
function GetData() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/AjaxUpdateChart.aspx",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: "callback",
    success: update,
    error: function () {
        setTimeout(GetData, updateInterval);
    }
  });
}
```

I'am doing the demo http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-ajax-update-chart.html,but it can't run.
What am I doing wrong? should I add or change anything in here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: that url does not serve jsonp ... not all api's do

Comment: I think the idea in the tutorial is to make your own backend service. That's why they supply some example source code for the *"Backend script"*